# How to calculate maximum/minimum over n-channels in Halide using domains?

Tags: c++, image-processing, halide

I am currently trying out Halide, playing around with calculating the maximum/minimum over all channels of an image. I would like to achieve this for a arbitrary images, where the amount of channels is only known at runtime.

I successfully got the following solution:

```
#include "Halide.h"
#include "halide_image_io.h"
using namespace Halide::Tools;

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    Halide::Buffer<uint8_t> input = load_image("rgb.png");

    Halide::Var x, y;
    Halide::Func max_channels, min_channels;
    max_channels(x, y) = input(x, y, 0);
    min_channels(x, y) = input(x, y, 0);
    for (int i = 1; i < input.channels(); ++i)
    {
        max_channels(x, y) = max(max_channels(x, y), input(x, y, i));
        min_channels(x, y) = min(min_channels(x, y), input(x, y, i));
    }

    {
        Halide::Buffer<uint8_t> output =
            max_channels.realize({input.width(), input.height(), 1});
        save_image(output, "maximum.png");
    }
    {
        Halide::Buffer<uint8_t> output =
            min_channels.realize({input.width(), input.height(), 1});
        save_image(output, "minimum.png");
    }
    printf("Success!\n");

    return 0;
}
```

However, I was wondering if it would be possible to achieve this without the explicit `for` loop. Going by the [documentation](https://halide-lang.org/docs/class_halide_1_1_r_dom.html), it should be possible to achieve this using the `Halide::RDom` class. From the examples given there, I would think that the following should work.

```
#include "Halide.h"
#include "halide_image_io.h"
using namespace Halide::Tools;

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    Halide::Buffer<uint8_t> input = load_image("rgb.png");

    Halide::Var x, y;
    Halide::Func max_channels, min_channels;
    Halide::RDom r(input);
    min_channels(x, y) = uint8_t{255};
    max_channels(x, y) = uint8_t{0};
    min_channels(r.x, r.y) = minimum(input(r.x, r.y, r.z));
    max_channels(r.x, r.y) = maximum(input(r.x, r.y, r.z));

    {
        Halide::Buffer<uint8_t> output =
            max_channels.realize({input.width(), input.height(), 1});
        save_image(output, "maximum.png");
    }
    {
        Halide::Buffer<uint8_t> output =
            min_channels.realize({input.width(), input.height(), 1});
        save_image(output, "minimum.png");
    }
    printf("Success!\n");

    return 0;
}
```

This compiles, but unfortunately crashes with the following error message:

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'Halide::CompileError'
what():  Error: In update definition 0 of Func "f1":
Tuple element 0 of update definition has type uint8, but pure definition has type int32

Aborted (core dumped)
```

This message does not make any sense to me, as all the values involved are `uint8_t`, so I am not sure where the programme is getting its `int32_t` from.

Thus, my question: *What is the correct way to calculate the maximum/minimum over all channels of an image using domains?* Or is this something that is not possible, and a `for` loop has to be used instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a way using the `maximum` and `minimum` helpers:

```
#include <Halide.h>
#include <halide_image_io.h>
using namespace Halide;
using namespace Halide::Tools;

int main() {
  Buffer<uint8_t> input = load_image("rgb.png");

  Var x, y;
  RDom r_chan(0, input.dim(2).extent());

  Func min_img;
  Func max_img;

  min_img(x, y) = minimum(input(x, y, r_chan));
  max_img(x, y) = maximum(input(x, y, r_chan));

  Buffer<uint8_t> min_out = min_img.realize({input.width(), input.height()});
  Buffer<uint8_t> max_out = max_img.realize({input.width(), input.height()});

  save_image(min_out, "min_out.png");
  save_image(max_out, "max_out.png");
}
```

You just need to create a reduction domain that spans the number of channels (given by `input.dim(2).extent()`). If you don't want to use the helpers, you can instead write (for example with `min_img`):

```
min_img(x, y) = cast<uint8_t>(255);
min_img(x, y) = min(input(x, y, r_chan), min_img(x, y));
```

The way reduction domains work (absent other scheduling directives) is they insert an innermost loop that repeats the rule for each point in the reduction domain. Thus the loops in this second example look like this:

```
for y:
  for x:
    min_img(...) = ...
for y:
  for x:
    for r_chan in [0, 2]:
      min_img(...) = ...
```

If you're worried about the optimizer not eliminating the first loop where it initializes everything to `255`, then you could instead write:

```
min_img(x, y) = undef(type_of<uint8_t>()); // skip the pure step
min_img(x, y) = min(
  input(x, y, r_chan),
  select(r_chan == 0, cast<uint8_t>(255), min_img(x, y))
);
```

I would expect LLVM to peel the first iteration (at least) in this case.

Comment: Ah. I see. You can run the domain over parts of the image! The documentation does not make it clear that this is possible... I thought your always had to define it over the whole image. By the way, is there a particular reason why you are using `input.dim(2).extent()` instead of `input.channels()`?

Comment: Nope. I just forgot about the shorthand

Comment: I see. Thank for the help, and for making my questions better.